# Build Error In Android for Javers version 3.11.4

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, javers

I am getting following error when I run the application in Device/emulator.

I have used Javers(3.11.4) for finding diff between two objects.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type without superclass: module-info
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:191)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.DefaultMethodClassFixer.visit(DefaultMethodClassFixer.java:80)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassVisitor.visit(ClassVisitor.java:113)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.InterfaceDesugaring.visit(InterfaceDesugaring.java:97)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:621)
at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)




Exception in thread "main" java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type com.google.common.collect.Multimap not present
    at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseSig(BytecodeDescriptor.java:85)
    at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:54)
    at sun.invoke.util.BytecodeDescriptor.parseMethod(BytecodeDescriptor.java:41)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodType.fromMethodDescriptorString(MethodType.java:1067)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.LambdaDesugaring$InvokedynamicRewriter.visitInvokeDynamicInsn(LambdaDesugaring.java:406)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:1623)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1126)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:698)
    at org.objectweb.asm.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:500)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarClassesInInput(Desugar.java:477)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugarOneInput(Desugar.java:361)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.desugar(Desugar.java:314)
    at com.google.devtools.build.android.desugar.Desugar.main(Desugar.java:711)
```

Comment: Never tried to run Javers on android. Witch Java version do you have? It seems like a classloader problem. Javers thinks that you are using Guava and tries to load comparators for Guava types, but it fails. How can I reproduce this issue?

Comment: Hi @BartekWalacik , I am using java 1.8 , you can add javers as dependency in android project and try to find difference between two objects